# Create a responsive gallery of images with the same size

Tags: html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using React and I'm trying with bootstrap to create a gallery of images with the same size. For now I put in a grid some images in this way

```
<img src=.... style={{maxWidth: "100%"}} class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"/>
```

In this way I obtain always responsive images with the same width but different height due to image proportions.

I want to find a way to wrap the image with a container that has fixed proportions. Obviously it is possible that I can see the height of image smaller then his container or that the image is cutted on the top and on the bottom but this isn't a problem for me.

For example if I have 3 images with these proportions:

- 100 x 300
- 400 x 100

I want see 2 thumbnails with the same size 200 x 200 and if I enlarge the screen size the thumbnails become both 400 x 400

Answer (score 0):

Try use this

https://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/jQuery-Responsive-Equal-Height-Images.html

```
<div class="pack">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x150"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x500"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300"/>
</div>

<!-- OR -->

<div class="pack">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <figcaption>Caption here</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x500">
    <figcaption>Caption here</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x150">
    <figcaption>Caption here</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-packed-img-strip.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="jquery-packed-img-strip.js"></script>

$(window).on('load', function() {
  $("div.pack").pack();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the below link. I created in code sandbox that shows the images in a fluid grid.
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tiny-tinker/FluidGrid

In the project, there's "GridImageViewer" component that receives "targetHeight" as a prop.
 This component adjusts the image's height to fit the target height so the image size will be different from the original.